# Automatic deletion of published WordPress posts

Tags: wordpress, function

I have created a custom post similar to WordPress posts that I want to delete automatically every time (for example, every day or every week).
Is there a function for this?
I know that you can delete trash posts with the following function

```
define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 10 );
```

But what about custom created posts?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this code will full fill your requirements.

````
// Define the custom post type that you want to delete automatically
$custom_post_type = 'your_custom_post_type';

// Function to delete the custom post type posts
function delete_custom_post_type_posts() {
    // Get all published posts of the custom post type
    $current_date = current_time('Y-m-d');
    $yesterday_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($current_date)));
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'date_query' => array(
            'after' => $yesterday_date,
            'before' => $current_date,
            'inclusive' => true
        )
    );
    
    $my_posts = get_posts( $args );
    
    // Loop through the posts and delete them
    foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ) {
        wp_delete_post( $my_post->ID, true );
    }
}

// Schedule the event to run every week
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'delete_custom_post_type_posts_event' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'twicedaily', 'delete_custom_post_type_posts_event' );
}

// Hook the function to the scheduled event
add_action( 'delete_custom_post_type_posts_event', 'delete_custom_post_type_posts' );```
````

Comment: I wish you all the best, my dear brother
I am very grateful to you

Comment: Hello again...thanks for your advice
I have a question
How can I define this function in terms of minutes and hours?
I want to test this code to see if it works or not, but to test it, I have to wait a day each time to see the result.
Is it possible to use, for example, the function time() + 3600 to determine the result after 60 minutes?

Comment: you have to dig this 'wp_schedule_event' function. 2nd parameter is time, you can change it as you want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can delete published posts every week by setting up a `wp_schedule_event`

Hope this code helps

```
// Define the custom post type that you want to delete automatically
$custom_post_type = 'your_custom_post_type';

// Function to delete the custom post type posts
function delete_custom_post_type_posts() {
    // Get all published posts of the custom post type
    $current_date = current_time('Y-m-d');
    $last_week_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week', strtotime($current_date)));
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'date_query' => array(
            'after' => $last_week_date,
            'before' => $current_date,
            'inclusive' => true
        )
    );
    
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    
    // Loop through the posts and delete them
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        wp_delete_post( $post->ID, true );
    }
}

// Schedule the event to run every week
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'delete_custom_post_type_posts_event' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'weekly', 'delete_custom_post_type_posts_event' );
}

// Hook the function to the scheduled event
add_action( 'delete_custom_post_type_posts_event', 'delete_custom_post_type_posts' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much
I will test the code and let you know
only one question
What if I want the posts to be deleted every day instead of a week?

Comment: change the time in wp_schedule_event function and post query

Comment: ```$today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'date_query' => array(
    array(
      'after' => $today,
      'inclusive' => true,
    ),
  ),
);```

Comment: Thank you very much
I tested different methods, but I could not achieve the desired result because I am not very familiar with PHP and WordPress functions and how to write them, unfortunately.
I would be grateful if you apply this change in the function itself and put the complete function here for me
Also, my post type is a type of custom content that is stored in the wp_hlhiwjet_cct_sssss database table, and its slug is sssss, so I don't know how to place this type of post type inside the function.
I would be very grateful if you could help me with these two things

Comment: Sorry I am not clear about your requirements

Comment: Thank you again
To explain more clearly, I want to delete a type of wordpress post that is similar to the post, automatically in a time interval of once every two days.
I want all posts to be deleted at once and in both days

Comment: Please rewrite the same function every two days. Thank you
I try to set the type of post type myself
Thank